# threads/edit-document REST API returns 500 "application_error" when setting data

Tags: quip, liveapps

I want to be able to set the data for a Quip live app.   I generated the hello world app using the quip cli and modified the code to declare the simple schema.

```typescript
    static getProperties() {
        return {
            isHighlighted: "boolean"
          };
    }
```

If I put `quip.apps.setPayload("{\"isHighlighted\":true}");` in the initialization callback, and then GET the document, I see this embedded in the `div`

`data-live-app-id='WMZAjAhgGfw' data-live-app-payload='{&quot;isHighlighted&quot;:true}'`

However, if I add the same `data-live-app-payload` attribute to the threads/edit-document POST API, then I get an error 500 message.   Note, changing the payload to an empty string returns a success (but obviously doesn't set the data like I would like)

How can I set the data for my Quip live app from the threads/edit-document POST API?  This seems like something everyone creating a Quip live app would want to do?

========
UPDATE

Using the "Kanban Board" Live App that is pre-published to a new Quip site, I can use the data-live-app-payload successfully.   When I took the source code for "Kanban Board" from https://github.com/quip/quip-apps, changed the app-id, built and republished, the live app behaves the same but any attempt to use data-live-app-payload attribute fails with the 500 error again.

Answer (score 0):

The `threads-edit-document` API can only be used to set live app data for a subset of built-in live apps. The limitation is noted [here](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation/current#operation/deleteThread:%7E:text=You%20can%20add%20only%20these%20types%20of%20live%20apps%20to%20a%20document%3A%20calendar%2C%20Salesforce%20record%2C%20Salesforce%20list%2C%20Kanban%20board%2C%20and%20project%20tracker.). Currently, you can add only these types of live apps to a document: calendar, Salesforce record, Salesforce list, Kanban board, and project tracker.

Comment: Thanks Jayant, I really appreciate you answering this question.  The text you linked to says this...

"You can add only these types of live apps to a document: calendar, Salesforce record, Salesforce list, Kanban board, and project tracker."

However, that is not true.   I can add my live app to the document without issue.   The thing I cannot do is set the payload data when adding the app.   The payload data can be stored programmatically by the live app but I was wanting to set it at creation time.